# Flutter - how to Center Scale Animation in GridView for each element?

Tags: flutter

I have a 4x3 gridview generated by a list (that may change in number of rows, colums), and want to apply a scale (using ScaleEffect) to the GridView elements that starts in the center of the overall gridview container (ie. between 6 and 7 for 4x3), before scaling down to its grid position. See the current scale (without alignment set) by default centers the scale over the element's position.

See this animated GIF image for the desired effect:

[image: gridview badges]

The challenge I am facing, is that each grid element needs a different alignment offset to start in the grid center since each element is in a different position. Is it possible to programmatically set the alignment parameter for this to work (see in code?), or perhaps it will require SlideEffect/MoveEffect rather than just ScaleEffect (since the start position will be the same for all elements), or a custom animation controller?

See the code below:

```
import 'package:flutter_animate/flutter_animate.dart';

//...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return SizedBox (
        child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 4, //<-- number of cols / rows may change
        children: List.generate(20, (index) { //<--element count may change
          return Center(
                child: Animate(
              delay: (1000*index).toInt().ms,
              effects: const [ScaleEffect( //<-- can it be done just with ScaleEffect?
                begin: Offset(4,4),
                end: Offset(1,1),
               // alignment: <-- needs to be different for each index to center?
                  )],
                    child: Text("${index+1}", )));
      }),
      ));
  }
```

Do you know how I could achieve this? I'd be grateful for any pointers or solution (ideally without additional packages).

Comment: means the effect will start from 9 item row ? can you include an gif that you are trying to get.

Comment: Thanks Yeasin - I have added a gif now showing the desired effect. This effect has been done combining SlideEffect and ScaleEffect with a manually calculated ScaleEffect begin: Offets (using a switch statement for 1-12 positions) to get the starting center point. However, I would like it calculated dynamically for any gridview cell position.